# auto layout not working after integrating

Tags: ios, xcode, xib, ios-autolayout

I have my xib set to use "Use AutoLayout" in my project. All the UI fits perfectly in iPhone 6 and iPad 2 when I build this project and run. However, if I copy this xib and related files to another project, I find that the UI layout does not fit and shrinks to top left after integration. All the UI does not fit perfectly as in the original project for iPhone6 and iPad 2.

When I examine the Xib in IB, I see all necessary constraints in place. Can anyone throw some light, as what might be happening here?

Comment: Please post some screenshot describing your problem...